# HUD commands from all applications?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, hud

I've just recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. In 12.04, I constantly used the HUD and, frequently, I fired commands from apps other than the active one. For example, I would be running any application and press ALT + "hiber..." to hibernate the computer. Another example would be using Firefox and press ALT + "stop..." to stop the current hamster task.

I don't get that behavior in 14.04 now, it looks like only actions from the active application appear. Is that the default behavior now? Any way to change it?

Comment: I'm missing this behaviour since 13.10, if I remember right. They changed it and I haven't found a way to customize it back yet.